# Custom Reset password templates forms doesn't show

Tags: django, django-forms, django-authentication

I modified the first password reset page successfully. (Where the user insert his email address)

Where it doesn't work it the Password Reset Confirm page (Where the users write his new password). When I click the link that I received by email to reset the password, it load my html template but it doesn't load my form. (Only load h1 tag and other things)

html template

```
{% load static %}

<div class="box" align="center">
  <h1>Write your new password</h1>
  <div class="small-line"></div>
  <form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ context.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" class="sendbut">Reset Password</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

forms.py

```
class SetPasswordForm(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SetPasswordForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    # …
    new_password1 = forms.CharField(
        label=("New password"),
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'autocomplete': 'new-password'}),
        strip=False,
        help_text=password_validation.password_validators_help_text_html(),
    )
    new_password2 = forms.CharField(
        label=("New password confirmation"),
        strip=False,
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'autocomplete': 'new-password'}),
    )
```

views.py

```
@sensitive_post_parameters()
@never_cache
def PasswordResetConfirmView(request, uidb64=None, token=None,
                           template_name='users/password_reset_confirm.html',
                           token_generator=default_token_generator,
                           set_password_form=SetPasswordForm,
                           post_reset_redirect=None,
                           current_app=None, extra_context=None):
    """
    View that checks the hash in a password reset link and presents a
    form for entering a new password.
    """
    UserModel = get_user_model()
    assert uidb64 is not None and token is not None  # checked by URLconf
    if post_reset_redirect is None:
        post_reset_redirect = reverse('password_reset_complete')
    else:
        post_reset_redirect = resolve_url(post_reset_redirect)
    try:
        # urlsafe_base64_decode() decodes to bytestring on Python 3
        uid = force_str(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
        user = UserModel._default_manager.get(pk=uid)
    except (TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, UserModel.DoesNotExist):
        user = None

    if user is not None and token_generator.check_token(user, token):
        validlink = True
        title = ('Enter new password')
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = set_password_form(user, request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect(post_reset_redirect)
        else:
            form = set_password_form(user)
    else:
        validlink = False
        form = None
        title = ('Password reset unsuccessful')
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'title': title,
        'validlink': validlink,
    }
    if extra_context is not None:
        context.update(extra_context)

    if current_app is not None:
        request.current_app = current_app

    return TemplateResponse(request, template_name, context)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('password_reset/', views.password_reset, name='password_reset'),
    path('password_reset/done/', views.password_reset_done, name="password_reset_done"),
    path(r'reset/<uidb64>/<token>/', views.PasswordResetConfirmView, name='password_reset_confirm'),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

### please write {{form.as_p}} insted of {{context.as_p}}

```
{% load static %}

<div class="box" align="center">
  <h1>Write your new password</h1>
  <div class="small-line"></div>
  <form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" class="sendbut">Reset Password</button>
  </form>
</div>
```